# How to animate allocated png image?

Tags: objective-c, animation, sprite-kit

I am making an Objective-C game which has a player allocated as follows:

```
self.player = [[Player alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"playerWalkAnimation1"];
self.player.position = CGPointMake(100, 50);
self.player.zPosition = 15;
self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.frame.size];
self.player.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
self.player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =  obs1Category;
self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obs1Category;
self.player.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
[self.map addChild:self.player];
```

How can I add a walk animation to this player image? It is a PNG, and when I play the game the image simply moves forward with a single image and not all the images that make up the entire animation. Is there a runAction or SKAction that will read all the images from 1 to finish and repeatForever?

Any advise is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes! [animateWithTextures:timePerFrame](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417828-animatewithtextures?language=objc) and
wrap it in a [repeatActionForever:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417676-repeatactionforever?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and get back here :)

Comment: Ok, See, I can make an image appear on the screen and make the animation run. Thanks for that, however I am trying to have the same Allocated image, read all sprites. So,

Comment: Im reposting my comment HERE:

Ok, See, I can make an image appear on the screen and make the animation run. Thanks for that, however I am trying to have working is:

@property (nonatomic, strong) Player *PLAYER;

self.PLAYER = [[Player alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"playerWalkAnimation1"]; 

// Player animation run??
self.PLAYER.animateWithTexture? = runAction NSArray *_heroWalkingFrames;?



(NOTE: The above mess just shows what I want to accomplish. Not actual code) Thanks

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how to do this with my self.player?

Comment: UPDATE. I was able to make the animation appear however I still have the static image behind the animated image. But I think that I can simply set the alpha to 0 and just use the animation. If this is acceptable I will accept your answer. I did notice that my node Count is making the game really slow.

Comment: No more errors. I was placing some of that code in the Update method. Since it runs every single frame, this was causing the problem. Moved it outside update and it works. Thanks

Comment: very good! yes, you can set the alpha to 0 or not in it it with an image. I usually init without texture enything is animated.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for taking the time to help with apparently useless questions :P Got downvoted :( Have a great week sabi!